# How to scroll UIStackView horizontally when VoiceOver swipe?

Tags: ios, uistackview, voiceover

I have a horizontal UIStackView with several buttons inside. The number of button is not constant and the length of stack view may exceed screen width.

[image]

I use the structure UIScrollView - UIView - UIStackView to right align when the length is shorter than screen width, and left align when the length exceeds.

Right align:
[image]
Left align:
[image]

When VoiceOver is on, it only read buttons in the screen.

I tried to add all buttons to accessibilityElements. VoiceOver can read all buttons but did not scroll the stack view to show them. And when swipe from the element below the stack view, VoiceOver still ignore buttons not in the screen. So adding to accessibilityElements cannot resolve this issue.

Anybody knows how to scroll stack view to show hiding buttons when user swipes screen? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @XLE_22 I tried the same as your edited answer, but it shows error: Scroll View - Need constraints for: X(Y) position or width(height).

Comment: weird because my screenshots are the exact results of what I coded under Xcode 11 and it worked as desired. I'll take a look when I have more time but take a look at the constraints I showed to be sure you have exactly the same. 

Comment: @XLE_22 Please check the below screenshot focusing on "My scroll view", there's the error icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to subclass UIButton and override its accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused method.

MyButton.h

```
@interface MyButton : UIButton

@property (weak, nonatomic) UIScrollView *scrollView;

@end
```

MyButton.m

```
#import "MyButton.h"

@implementation MyButton

- (void)accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused
{
    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height) animated:YES];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

> Anybody knows how to scroll stack view to show hiding buttons when user swipe screen?

**Embed the stack view inside a scroll view** to be able to get the elements outside the screen: you can do this with in the [Interface Builder](https://medium.com/@mufakkharulislamnayem/scrolling-in-a-horizontal-uistackview-with-storyboard-e02a9aab555b) or [programmatically](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/scrolling-stack-views/).

Here's my configuration under Xcode to swipe buttons with VoiceOver inside a `UIStackView`:
[image]
[image]
And I finally get the following result on my device:
[image]
I haven't played with alignment in the `UIStackView` but, with this rationale, you can **scroll stack view to show hiding buttons when user swipes screen**.

⚠️ ⬛️◼️▪️ **EDIT**  ▪️◼️⬛️ ⚠️ *(February 2020: after added new constraints in the original question)*

> The alignment is my primary need.

As explained in my comment, the layout constraints are the solution to reach your goal without using a dedicated `UIView`.

I detail the Interface Builder configuration hereunder:
[image]
[image]
And with few lines of code as follows:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myScrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var myStackView: UIStackView!

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let delta = myScrollView.frame.width - myStackView.frame.width
    let constant = (delta > 0.0) ? delta : 0.0

    myStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: myScrollView.contentLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor,
                                         constant: constant).isActive = true
}
```

... you get this result with 5 buttons:
[image]
... and the right alignment is kept with few buttons:
[image]

Now, you can **scroll UIStackView horizontally when VoiceOver swipe**.

Comment: This doesn't work for my case. It won't scroll automatically when there's a UIView between UIScrollView and UIStackView.

Comment: Directly embed the stack view in a scroll view cannot make it right align when its length is shorter than screen width and left align when it's longer. The alignment is my primary need, so I have to put a UIView between to make this possible.